# (run-main-0) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, nosuchmethoderror

I got a problem when I used *sbt* to run a spark job, I have finish compile, but when I run the command `run`, I got the problem below

```
 [error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$.empty()Lscala/collection/immutable/HashSet;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$.empty()Lscala/collection/immutable/HashSet;
    at akka.actor.ActorCell$.<init>(ActorCell.scala:305)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell$.<clinit>(ActorCell.scala)
    at akka.actor.RootActorPath.$div(ActorPath.scala:152)
    at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.<init>(ActorRefProvider.scala:465)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.<init>(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$2.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:78)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
```

Anyone knows what should I do?

Comment: Whats your version of spark and scala? My initial guess would be that the scala versions are mismatching.

Comment: @JustinPihony  Thanks for you help, my scala version is 2.10.5   and  spark version is 1.3.0,can you tell me how to judge whether the scala match or not?

Answer (score 19):

I met with the same error when I used scala-library-2.11 jar But when I replaced it with scala-library-2.10 jar . It runs fine

Answer (score 8):

It is probably caused by using incompatible versions of Scala. When I downgraded from Scala 2.11 to 2.10, I forgot to modify one package version (so one package used 2.11, the rest 2.10), resulting in having the same error.

Note: I only had this problem when using IntelliJ.

Answer (score 7):

If you are getting the error and here because you cannot run Jupiter notebooks with Spark 2.1 and Scala 2.11 below is how I was able to make it work. Assumes you installed Jupiter and toree

**Pre-req** -
Make sure Docker is running else Make fails. 
Make sure gpg is installed else Make fails.

**Build steps -**

```
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/<path>/spark-2.1.0-hadoop2.7/ 
git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree.git 
cd incubator-toree 
make clean release APACHE_SPARK_VERSION=2.1.0 
pip install --upgrade ./dist/toree-pip/toree-0.2.0.dev1.tar.gz 
pip freeze |grep toree 
jupyter toree install --spark_home=$SPARK_HOME
```

========================================================================

**To Start the notebook** - 
    SPARK_OPTS='--master=local[4]' jupyter notebook

Comment: Link to Jira issue: [Toree not working with Apache Spark 2.0.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOREE-336)

Answer (score 6):

I used these versions and everything works now.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the scala version you are using corresponds to the precompiled spark version.
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be reproduced with version `2.11.8`.

By the moment, no downgrade is required.
Just update `scala-library` version to *2.12.0*.

Answer (score 0):

I've the exactly the same problem and got it fixed by downgrading scala 2.11.8 to 2.10.6.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue but where do i alter the scala-library version?

Installation (on Ubuntu 16.04):

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
wget http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz && tar xvf spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
pip install toree && jupyter toree install
```

So when I start with a notebook it tells me that I use a different scala version. But I haven't installed anything else.
[screenshot + scala version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMYGn.png)

My spark jars folder contains an `scala-library-2.11.8.jar` file. But how tell torree to use that (or another) file for scala.

Answer (score 0):

To me both scala versions 2.11 and 2.12 dint work , downgrading to 2.10.3 worked