# How to install an older version of scala

Tags: scala

I currently had installed `scala 2.11.7` but in order to fix [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339005/run-main-0-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-scala-collection-immutable-hashset-emp), I have to install a older version of scala(`2.10.5`). When I try to install with brew, I keep getting the following error

```
Error: No available formula for 2.10.5
```

I tried downloading the binaries for scala download page but when I load the SDK and all the libraries in `IntelliJ`, I just get this error

```
Error:scalac: No 'scala-library*.jar' in Scala compiler classpath in Scala SDK scala-sdk-2.10.5
```

So what is the right way to install an older version of scala and setting the same in intellij

Comment: Is there a download page with direct links for HTTP download? I need the `scala-library.jar` with a checksum of `458d046151ad179c85429ed7420ffb1eaf6ddf85`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you manage your project with `sbt`, the scala built tool, either directly or via *IntelliJ*, the version of *scala* for that code is defined in the build file (`build.sbt` or `Build.scala`):

```
scalaVersion  := "2.10.5"
```

Choosing this path, there isn't even a need to install scala on your Mac at all. Each project will have its own version -- pulled from your local `ivy` repository, so it doesn't have to download it each time.

And rather than typing `scala` to get to the REPL, you type `sbt console` to get to the REPL with the project's scala version and dependencies loaded.

Comment: I tried `sbt` but was having issues syncing with intellij. Do you have any links to guide me though the usage of `sbt`?

Comment: With IDEA 14.x it's gotten pretty full proof. I wrote it up here: https://gist.github.com/sdether/ea9196b10cdb46757d5f Main caveat is the waiting after you create the project as now it will resolve the scala version, download it and its dependencies, all of which takes a while.

Answer (score 38):

The following should work for Homebrew 0.9.5:

Install Tapped version of Scala 2.10

```
brew install homebrew/versions/scala210
```

Unlink version of Scala 2.11 (if installed)

```
brew unlink scala
```

Link Tapped version of Scala 2.10

```
brew link scala210 --force
```

Check scala version

```
scala -version
```

Comment: I am not able to use the `brew switch` command to switch between the versions after this. I always have to do a link and unlink. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I created the following aliases to help me for the time being. `# Setup the following aliases`
`alias use_scala210='brew unlink scala && brew unlink scala210 && brew link scala210 --force'`
`alias use_scala211='brew unlink scala && brew unlink scala210 && brew link scala'`

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: This answer may need to be updated, I attempted to `brew install homebrew/versions/scala210` and i got this response `Error: homebrew/versions was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.`

Answer (score 30):

```
brew search scala
```

then you will find all the available versions like below

```
scala                     scala@2.10                scala@2.11                scalaenv                  scalariform               scalastyle
homebrew/science/scalapack                                                     Caskroom/cask/scala-ide
```

Then choose whichever version you want to install. say if you want to install scala 2.11 then you can do that by runnig the command like below

```
brew install scala@2.11
```

Answer (score 5):

Homebrew installs scala 2.10.5 with the formula scala210:

```
$ brew install scala210
==> Installing scala210 from homebrew/homebrew-versions
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/scala210-2.10.5.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz

==> Downloading http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-2.10.5.tgz
######################################################################## 100,0%
```

However, if you are using a build tool like maven or sbt, you should be able to set another scala version in your build config. You should then be able to import your project into *IntelliJ* and *IntelliJ* should automatically use the dependencies defined in your build config.

Comment: @Rahul have you tried upgrading brew? I'm running version 0.9.5

Comment: Yes, I have upgraded brew. This is my current version - Homebrew 0.9.5 (git revision 596b9; last commit 2015-09-24)

Comment: I am not able to use the `brew switch` command to switch between the versions after this. I always have to do a link and unlink. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Using brew to install specific version:

```
$ brew search scala
==> Formulae
scala                scala@2.10           scala@2.11            scalaenv             
scalapack            scalariform          scalastyle

==> Casks
scala-ide
```

Make sure you default version in profile

```
$echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/scala@2.11/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```