# How to switch to different version of Scala? (MacOS)

Tags: macos, scala, apache-spark, version

I have installed Scala 2.12.5 and trying to use Spark 2.2.0

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0"`

But read somewhere that Spark does not exist for that version of Scala.

How do I install scala 2.11.x and how to use it (e.g. switch to 2.11.x and then when needed - switch back to 2.12.x)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767204/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-scala?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

I'd personally suggest you use the sbt file to specify the scala version like this: `scalaVersion  := "2.11.x"`

then install with: `brew install scala@2.11.x`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using sbt based on the dependency line in your question.  In this case it's easy, just change the `scalaVersion` line to

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
```

Or whichever version you need.